# Are there any libraries providing mouse-driven zoom/pan for pure AS3 projects?

Tags: actionscript-3

Today I wanted to add mouse-driven zoom and pan functionality to a pure AS3 project - something like the Google Maps interface. I was surprised that I couldn't find a good package or library to do this already - I'm using FlashDevelop rather than Flash CS3, so the [nice VCam tool available as an FLA](http://bryanheisey.com/blog/?page_id=18) is no use.

There's nothing very complicated involved in implementing zoom/pan, although it can be fiddly and time-consuming to get right, but since zooming and panning are pretty common things to want to do I wondered if anyone could suggest a 'correct' way to do this in the Flash world, or a good library available that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for in the flare library's [PanZoomControl](http://flare.prefuse.org/api/flare/vis/controls/PanZoomControl.html):

> Interactive control for panning and
>   zooming a "camera". Any sprite can be
>   treated as a camera onto its drawing
>   content and display list children. To pan and zoom
>   over a collection of objects, simply
>   add a PanZoomControl for the sprite
>   holding the collection.

```
var s:Sprite; // a sprite holding a collection of items   
new PanZoomControl().attach(s); // attach pan and zoom controls to the sprite
```

The mouse controls are also implemented as you'd expect:

> Once a PanZoomControl has been
>   created, panning is performed by
>   clicking and dragging. Zooming is
>   performed either by scrolling the
>   mouse wheel or by clicking and
>   dragging vertically while the control
>   key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3D library such as [Papervision3D](http://dev.papervision3d.org/) or [FIVe3D](http://five3d.mathieu-badimon.com/). Then just move your camera based on different mouse events/gestures. Or use the built in z-axis in FlashPlayer 10 to get the zoom effect.

Comment: Papervision3D looks pretty good, but it doesn't tie into the mouse controls as neatly as Flare's PanZoomControl.